# Create a lookup table using Verilog ModelSim

Tags: verilog, lookup-tables

I am trying to create lookup tables that contain 256 elements. I searched a couple of websites and the best way seemed to create a 2D array since a case structure is very long for my application (I will need 7 other tables).

```
module LUTE1 (clk, address, data);

input clk;
input [7:0] address;
output reg [31:0] data;         

reg [31:0] LTE1 [0:255];
```

The   above compiles fine but it gives the error when I add the below.

```
 LTE1 = '{

        32'ha5c66363, 32'h84f87c7c, 32'h99ee7777, 32'h8df67b7b, 32'h0dfff2f2, 32'hbdd66b6b, 32'hb1de6f6f, 32'h5491c5c5,
        32'h50603030, 32'h03020101, 32'ha9ce6767, 32'h7d562b2b, 32'h19e7fefe, 32'h62b5d7d7, 32'he64dabab, 32'h9aec7676,
        32'h458fcaca, 32'h9d1f8282, 32'h4089c9c9, 32'h87fa7d7d, 32'h15effafa, 32'hebb25959, 32'hc98e4747, 32'h0bfbf0f0,
        32'hec41adad, 32'h67b3d4d4, 32'hfd5fa2a2, 32'hea45afaf, 32'hbf239c9c, 32'hf753a4a4, 32'h96e47272, 32'h5b9bc0c0,
        32'hc275b7b7, 32'h1ce1fdfd, 32'hae3d9393, 32'h6a4c2626, 32'h5a6c3636, 32'h417e3f3f, 32'h02f5f7f7, 32'h4f83cccc,
        32'h5c683434, 32'hf451a5a5, 32'h34d1e5e5, 32'h08f9f1f1, 32'h93e27171, 32'h73abd8d8, 32'h53623131, 32'h3f2a1515,
        32'h0c080404, 32'h5295c7c7, 32'h65462323, 32'h5e9dc3c3, 32'h28301818, 32'ha1379696, 32'h0f0a0505, 32'hb52f9a9a,
        32'h090e0707, 32'h36241212, 32'h9b1b8080, 32'h3ddfe2e2, 32'h26cdebeb, 32'h694e2727, 32'hcd7fb2b2, 32'h9fea7575,
        32'h1b120909, 32'h9e1d8383, 32'h74582c2c, 32'h2e341a1a, 32'h2d361b1b, 32'hb2dc6e6e, 32'heeb45a5a, 32'hfb5ba0a0,
        32'hf6a45252, 32'h4d763b3b, 32'h61b7d6d6, 32'hce7db3b3, 32'h7b522929, 32'h3edde3e3, 32'h715e2f2f, 32'h97138484,
        32'hf5a65353, 32'h68b9d1d1, 32'h00000000, 32'h2cc1eded, 32'h60402020, 32'h1fe3fcfc, 32'hc879b1b1, 32'hedb65b5b,
        32'hbed46a6a, 32'h468dcbcb, 32'hd967bebe, 32'h4b723939, 32'hde944a4a, 32'hd4984c4c, 32'he8b05858, 32'h4a85cfcf,
        32'h6bbbd0d0, 32'h2ac5efef, 32'he54faaaa, 32'h16edfbfb, 32'hc5864343, 32'hd79a4d4d, 32'h55663333, 32'h94118585,
        32'hcf8a4545, 32'h10e9f9f9, 32'h06040202, 32'h81fe7f7f, 32'hf0a05050, 32'h44783c3c, 32'hba259f9f, 32'he34ba8a8,
        32'hf3a25151, 32'hfe5da3a3, 32'hc0804040, 32'h8a058f8f, 32'had3f9292, 32'hbc219d9d, 32'h48703838, 32'h04f1f5f5,
        32'hdf63bcbc, 32'hc177b6b6, 32'h75afdada, 32'h63422121, 32'h30201010, 32'h1ae5ffff, 32'h0efdf3f3, 32'h6dbfd2d2,
        32'h4c81cdcd, 32'h14180c0c, 32'h35261313, 32'h2fc3ecec, 32'he1be5f5f, 32'ha2359797, 32'hcc884444, 32'h392e1717,
        32'h5793c4c4, 32'hf255a7a7, 32'h82fc7e7e, 32'h477a3d3d, 32'hacc86464, 32'he7ba5d5d, 32'h2b321919, 32'h95e67373,
        32'ha0c06060, 32'h98198181, 32'hd19e4f4f, 32'h7fa3dcdc, 32'h66442222, 32'h7e542a2a, 32'hab3b9090, 32'h830b8888,
        32'hca8c4646, 32'h29c7eeee, 32'hd36bb8b8, 32'h3c281414, 32'h79a7dede, 32'he2bc5e5e, 32'h1d160b0b, 32'h76addbdb,
        32'h3bdbe0e0, 32'h56643232, 32'h4e743a3a, 32'h1e140a0a, 32'hdb924949, 32'h0a0c0606, 32'h6c482424, 32'he4b85c5c,
        32'h5d9fc2c2, 32'h6ebdd3d3, 32'hef43acac, 32'ha6c46262, 32'ha8399191, 32'ha4319595, 32'h37d3e4e4, 32'h8bf27979,
        32'h32d5e7e7, 32'h438bc8c8, 32'h596e3737, 32'hb7da6d6d, 32'h8c018d8d, 32'h64b1d5d5, 32'hd29c4e4e, 32'he049a9a9,
        32'hb4d86c6c, 32'hfaac5656, 32'h07f3f4f4, 32'h25cfeaea, 32'hafca6565, 32'h8ef47a7a, 32'he947aeae, 32'h18100808,
        32'hd56fbaba, 32'h88f07878, 32'h6f4a2525, 32'h725c2e2e, 32'h24381c1c, 32'hf157a6a6, 32'hc773b4b4, 32'h5197c6c6,
        32'h23cbe8e8, 32'h7ca1dddd, 32'h9ce87474, 32'h213e1f1f, 32'hdd964b4b, 32'hdc61bdbd, 32'h860d8b8b, 32'h850f8a8a,
        32'h90e07070, 32'h427c3e3e, 32'hc471b5b5, 32'haacc6666, 32'hd8904848, 32'h05060303, 32'h01f7f6f6, 32'h121c0e0e,
        32'ha3c26161, 32'h5f6a3535, 32'hf9ae5757, 32'hd069b9b9, 32'h91178686, 32'h5899c1c1, 32'h273a1d1d, 32'hb9279e9e,
        32'h38d9e1e1, 32'h13ebf8f8, 32'hb32b9898, 32'h33221111, 32'hbbd26969, 32'h70a9d9d9, 32'h89078e8e, 32'ha7339494,
        32'hb62d9b9b, 32'h223c1e1e, 32'h92158787, 32'h20c9e9e9, 32'h4987cece, 32'hffaa5555, 32'h78502828, 32'h7aa5dfdf,
        32'h8f038c8c, 32'hf859a1a1, 32'h80098989, 32'h171a0d0d, 32'hda65bfbf, 32'h31d7e6e6, 32'hc6844242, 32'hb8d06868,
        32'hc3824141, 32'hb0299999, 32'h775a2d2d, 32'h111e0f0f, 32'hcb7bb0b0, 32'hfca85454, 32'hd66dbbbb, 32'h3a2c1616
    };


endmodule
```

The program is giving the following errors:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/LUTE1.v(9): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.

** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/LUTE1.v(9): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'LTE1'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

Answer (score 1):

First a quick note: the `'{}` syntax is SystemVerilog. Verilog can assign a whole array through system task (e.g. `$readmemb` or PLA modeling task). It cannot assign a whole array in a single assignment.

`LTE1 = '{...};` needs to be in an procedural (`initial` or `always` block) or continuous assignment (`assign` statement and must be a wire type, not reg). You can also assign the array in as part of the declaration: `logic [31:0] LTE1 [0:255] = '{...};`

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing "wrong" or "inefficient" about using a large case statement to implement a lookup table. The compiler / synthesis tool would implement the same logic as if you were trying to use the huge two-dimensional array (in SystemVerilog).

This is just fine:

```
case (address)
    8'd0: data_temp = 32'ha5c66363;
    8'd1: data_temp = 32'h84f87c7c;
    8'd2: data_temp = 32'h99ee7777;
    ...
```

There's a bit more text in the code for the large case statement, but efficient use of a good text editor (or even a simple script) can simplify the task of actually creating the code.